# Passing generator vs list for Python any

Tags: python

Given a list of integers such as `integers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

I would like to know if there is an even number in the list using Python's [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function. My question is if it is more efficient to pass a list comprehension outcome like so:

```
evens = [each for each in integers if each % 2 == 0]
has_even = any(evens)
```

versus using a generator such as:

```
has_even = any(each for each in integers if each % 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to pass a generator than a list comprehension to `any` and `all`. Both of those functions can short-circuit, i.e., `any` will stop as soon as it encounters a `True` value, and `all` will stop as soon as it encounters a `False` value. If you pass them a list comprehension the whole list has to be built before `any` / `all` can start work, but if you pass them a generator then only the needed vales will be generated. So not only do you save RAM using a generator, you may save a substantial amount of execution time, too.

Your generator can be made more efficient; the `if` part is redundant.

```
has_even = any(each % 2 == 0 for each in integers)
```

Answer (score 2):

`any` with a generator is the most efficient method here as it will not allocate the list of all even numbers and moreover it will stop at the first even number, not even considering others. The input could also be a generator (e.g. reading numbers from a file) and in this case the saving is bigger if you stop reading the input.

`any` with a generator is also very readable, especially if you define an `even` predicate...

```
def even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0

if any(even(x) for x in integers):
    ...
```

Readability should be for most software your primary concern (computers today are generally very fast).

If your eyes are trained with the functional approach then an even more readable version could be

```
if any(filter(even, integers)):
   ...
```

that with Python 3 is also as efficient (not extracting input from `numbers` once the result is known).

Note however that if efficiency for this kind of computation is your most important concern then Python is probably the wrong tool...